# cant access data in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote this function which takes in a `post id` and finds the `last name` for that `post id`.When I run this I get error :

> database.cursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

What is wrong?

```
            public Person_Obj GetPerson_Obj(int post_id)
{
    Person_Obj obj = new Person_Obj();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Persons  + " WHERE "
            + Post_Id  + " = " + post_id;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


     if (cursor != null)
         cursor.moveToFirst();


    obj.set_last_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LastName")));


    return obj;
}
```

Comment: See how looks formed request, maybe he does not return any result. Also you need to change Cursor check. In this code you try to move cursor to the first position, but you don't handle option when cursor size is 0.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @DaveMorrissey-Noo i have not solved it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("query", null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                // write your code
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();
```